# Viewing single column of data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, view

I am running a simulation model that creates a large data frame as its output, with each column corresponding to the time-series of a particular variable:

```
data5<-as.data.frame(simulation3$baseline)
```

Occasionally I want to look at subsets, especially particular columns, of this data frame in order to get an idea of the output. For this I am using the View-function like so

```
View(data5[1:100,1])
```

for instance, if I wish to see the first 100 rows of column 1. Alternatively, I also sometimes do something like this, using the names of the time series:

```
timeframe=1:100
toAnalyse=c("u","u_n","u_e","u_nw")
View(data5[timeframe,toAnalyse])
```

In either case, there is an annoying display problem when I am trying to view a single column on its own (as for instance with View(data5[1:100,1])), whereby what I get looks like this:

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QqpW.png)

As you can see, the top of the table which would usually contain the name of the variable in the dataset instead contains a string of all values that the variable takes. This problem does not appear if I select 2 or more columns:

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReN9f.png)

Does anyone know how to get rid of this issue? Is there some argument that I can feed to View to make sure that it behaves nicely when I ask it to just show a single column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`View(data5[1:100,1, drop=FALSE])`

When you access a single column of a data frame it is converted to a vector, `drop=FALSE` prevents that and retains the column name.

For instance:

```
> df
  n  s    b
1 2 aa TRUE
2 3 bb TRUE
3 5 cc TRUE
> df[, 1]
[1] 2 3 5
> df[, 1, drop=FALSE]
  n
1 2
2 3
3 5
```

Comment: You can also use `dplyr::select()` to avoid this issue.